# Trigger is covered by tests, but can't create package because it isn't covered

Tags: trigger, unit-test, code-coverage, package, deployment

I'm in charge of managing packages of an app my company is creating, and I'm facing one of those 'Salesforce bugs' that don't tell you what is wrong.

In the app we have some triggers, and when trying to create a package, Salesforce tells me that two triggers don't have coverage. However, my tests run do cover those two triggers. I have even checked both in MavensMate and in the org's Developer Console.

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: Are you sure that all the test classes have been added to the managed package? Because there is no dependency from the product components to the tests that can be automatically detected the tests have to be manually added.

Comment: That is indeed a good point. Most of the classes and components where added automatically, and I didn't notice those two tests weren't. Can you please answer this question so I can mark it as solved? Thank you! :)

Comment: I've made the comment an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that all the test classes have been added to the managed package?

Because there is no dependency from the product components to the tests (so there can be be no automatic detection of the tests) the tests have to be manually added.